# Creating a certain data pattern using python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

```
<TEXT>John became the first writer to get the 1000 reviews. His writing drew praise from all over the globe.
Now he wishes to do even better.</TEXT>
<TAGS>
<PERSONAL spans="13~29" text="the first writer"/>
<PERSONAL spans="61~85" text="drew praise from all over"/>
</TAGS>
```

Here is an XML file that I have to parse and generate a training file out of it. 
I have to search for the text in the PERSONAL tags and match it with the text in the TEXT tags. Whenever there is a match, the words in the PERSONAL tags need to be tagged as 'PERSONAL'

OUTPUT needs to be sth like this

```
John 
became
the PERSONAL
first PERSONAL
writer PERSONAL 
to 
get 
1000 
reviews 

His 
writing 
drew PERSONAL
praise PERSONAL
from PERSONAL
all PERSONAL
over PERSONAL
the 
globe
```

Code so far:

```
  root=ET.fromstring(data)
    maintext = root.find('TEXT').text
    sentences= re.split('.', context_text)             
    for tags in list(root):
        for pers in tags.findall('PERSONAL'):
             personal=pers.get('text')
             span=pers.get('spans')
             answer_start=((re.split('([^-]*)~', span))[1])
             answer_end=((re.split('([^-]*)~', span))[2])

        for sents in sentences:
             words=re.split(' ', sents)
             for word in words:
                   if personal in sents:
                       if word in (main_text[int(answer_start):int(answer_end)]):
                          print(word+' PERSONAL')
                       else: 
                          print(word)
                    else:
                        print(word)
```

Here, an extra 'the' in "John became the first writer to get **the** 1000 reviews" gets tagged as 'PERSONAL' as well. Some logical problem tagging it correctly which I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: Does the code not work?

Comment: @PeterWood I get unwanted tags as well. Now, I don't even know if this is the right way to approach this.

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: Suppose the sentence was , 'John became the first writer to get the 1000 reviews.' . I added an extra 'the'. According to the output, 'the first writer' needs to be tagged and not the extra 'the'; but it gets tagged as well.

Comment: Edit the question